# Problemas ao clicar com javascript ( npm puppeeter )

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, puppeteer

Bom dia, tarde ou noite leitor. Como o titulo diz, estou criando uma aplicação para automatizar meu instagram com o puppeteer e cheguei nesse botão, no qual eu não estou conseguindo clicar.

Já tentei usar page.waitForSelector e page.click e nada funciona... Minha ultima tentativa foi:

`await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});`

`await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('a.-nal3').click(); });`

Imagem do botão pelo inspecionar elemento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem tem ideia do que eu estou errando?